# SQL Query Results Using Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to do this query to display the names of the stores and the quantity of each book sold with only using joins but I tried to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.stor_name, t.title, s.qty
FROM stores x
INNER JOIN discounts d
ON x.stor_id=d.stor_id
INNER JOIN salesdetail s
ON d.stor_id=s.stor_id
INNER JOIN titles t
ON s.title_id=t.title_id
ORDER BY s.qty desc;
```

but that only displayed one of the stores results set for 'Bookbeat'.

[image]I tried to use Left, Right & Full Outer joins to no avail so I'm wondering how I would go about doing that query to display the names for the other stores that are not displaying their result set. As there is 7 stores and only 1 is displaying it's results.

[image]

The [link](http://pastebin.com/hDTPShdc) is a pastebin to the database.

And this is the schema.

[image]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without more information about your schema - it strikes me as wrong-ish that you're joining to discounts *only* on stor_id.  I'd expect discounts to be applied to different titles, not store-wide... and I wouldn't expect discounts to be always-enabled.  Try running it without the discounts inner join.  Futzing around with "Distinct" and outer joins is almost always the wrong approach with things like this

I see from your profile you're a first-year.  Is this schoolwork?  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I uploaded the schema to the database, does that help? I'm just trying to revise sql as I've forgot a bit over the summer, just started 2nd year and it's just been revision for the first few weeks.

Comment: Absolutely - the pastebin even moreso.  And as I suspected, the "Discounts" smells wrong.  First of all, it has that bizarre FK relationship to the SalesDetails table... but think about it, does Discounts store any per-title information?  No, it's store-wide.  So mentally, think of it as extra data tacked onto the Store.  The next question is whether discounts are really 1-1 to store... or are they 0..1 to Store.  I'd encourage you to examine the Discounts table and see if every store has a discount.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean now, thanks. I joined it using the sales table and it's displaying the other stores.

Comment: I'd re-draw that schema, now that I've looked at the DB script file, the quantities on your relationships are wrong in the case of discounts - you've even got its primary key wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there was something wrong with the table from when I began running queries on it but it's not mine. It's the one we work on in the labs that one of the lecturers created in a bit of a hurry I believe.

Comment: The tables themselves are fine, it's the schema diagram that's wrong.